# Probability (permutation or combination)

Tags: probability

A factory has 8 ingredients to make hand lotions, from which one ingredient is to be chosen as base weights of 100mg per gm, and another 4 ingredients are to be selected as supplementary with weights of 3mg per gm. How many different possible hand lotions can be made form these ingredients?

For me I will just use 8C1 x 7C4=280. Is it a correct approach? Or should I use permutation?

Answer (score 1):

That looks good to me. Once you have chosen the "base" ingredient, then it's clear that you have $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to choose the remaining ingredients. As there are $8$ ways to choose the base ingredient, you'll want a factor of $8$.

Comment: so the answer should be 280 right? Or should I multiply it by 8?

Comment: You're right. I was just explaining why it's $8*\binom{7}{4} = 280$